# C# Url Builder Class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I often end up rolling my own wrapper/extension methods for/around System.Uri and was wondering if anyone knows of a good open source implementation.  What I like to do most is parse querystring parameters, build a new query string (this is the key), and replace page names.  Got any good ones, or is System.Uri good enough for you?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

BradVin's [QueryString Builder](http://weblogs.asp.net/bradvincent/archive/2008/10/27/helper-class-querystring-builder-chainable.aspx) class is good.  Fluent interface and support for encryption.

It's also worth checking out this [UrlBuilder](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/UrlBuilder.aspx) class on CodeProject.  Similar to *System.UriBuilder* has better support for working with the QueryString.

Comment: Kudos on this answer.  This is almost verbatim what I've been rolling with for years.  Don't like the UriBuilder because I want more  functionality around dynamically adding qs parameters.

Answer (score 12):

[Flurl](https://flurl.io) [disclosure: I'm the author] is a fluent URL builder that looks like this:

```
var url = "http://www.some-api.com"
    .AppendPathSegment("endpoint")
    .SetQueryParams(new {
        api_key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeApiKey"],
        max_results = 20,
        q = "Don't worry, I'll get encoded!"
    });
```

If you happen to be building URLs for the purpose of calling them, [Flurl.Http](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/fluent-http) is a companion lib that lets you do HTTP off the fluent chain:

```
await "https://api.mysite.com"
    .AppendPathSegment("person")
    .SetQueryParams(new { ap_key = "my-key" })
    .WithOAuthBearerToken("MyToken")
    .PostJsonAsync(new { first_name = firstName, last_name = lastName });
```

Get the full package on NuGet:

`PM> Install-Package Flurl.Http`

or just the stand-alone URL builder:

`PM> Install-Package Flurl`

Answer (score 6):

We do use our own alternative Uri class that is partially based on Uri, as you say. However, I think there's an important distinction to be made - **System.Uri is generally intended to be immutable - or, more precisely, behave immutably.** Once one comes into existence, it represents a precise universal location/resource endpoint. If you need to describe a different location, you should create a new Uri, not change the existing one.

There's a separate class that specializes in producing Uri's: [UriBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder_members.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Between `System.Uri` and `System.UriBuilder`, what features exactly are you missing from those two?

Comment: Uri is immutable like Rex M clarified.  But I didn't even know about UriBuilder.  Will look into it.

Answer (score 2):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The arguments must be like: varName1, varValue1, varName2, varValue2 and so on.
    /// Empty names will be not be added to the result.
    /// Returns a string of the form varName1=varValue1&varName2=varValue2...
    /// </summary>    
    public static string BuildQueryString(params string[] strings)
    {
        Debug.Assert(0 == strings.GetLength(0) % 2);

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(50);
        bool isName = true;
        bool isEmptyName = false;

        foreach (string crtString in strings)
        {
            isEmptyName = (isName && string.IsNullOrEmpty(crtString)) ||
                (!isName && isEmptyName);

            if (!isEmptyName)
            {
                builder.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(crtString));

                if (isName)
                    builder.Append("=");
                else
                    builder.Append("&");
            }

            isName = !isName;
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a very nice new open source project on CodePlex that allows you to read, write, encrypt Uris and a bit more. Check them out!

[http://querystrings.codeplex.com](http://querystrings.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do (examples would help) but it sounds like you are trying to get some of the functionality of Apache's mod_rewrite in ASP.NET.

There is [an article at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx) about exactly this.