# Adding querystring to REST GET

Tags: c#, web-services, rest

I am trying to create a GET request to a REST webservice that reuires an Authorization token as a querystring parameter. So, The request needs to be in the format:

http://endpoint.com/action/resource?Auth=12345

I am drawing a blank as how to add the querystring to my HttpWebRequest without just building a string. Is there another (read: better) option?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [How to build a query string for a URL in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829080/how-to-build-a-query-string-for-a-url-in-c)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Url Builder Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759881/c-url-builder-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QueryString Builder](http://weblogs.asp.net/bradvincent/archive/2008/10/27/helper-class-querystring-builder-chainable.aspx) class is good and has a fluent interface.

Also [UrlBuilder](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/UrlBuilder.aspx) class on CodeProject. Similar to System.UriBuilder has better support for working with the QueryString.