# URL string generation in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I was wondering if .NET had any class used to ease URL generation, similar to **Path.Combine** but for URLs.

Example of functionality I'm looking for:

```
string url = ClassName.Combine("http://www.google.com", "index")
            .AddQueryParam("search", "hello world").AddQueryParam("pagenum", 3);
// Result: http://www.google.com/index?search=hello%20world&pagenum=3
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Url Builder Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759881/c-sharp-url-builder-class)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [`UriBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx) class.

> Provides a custom constructor for uniform resource identifiers (URIs) and modifies URIs for the Uri class.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a similar question which links to two third party libraries:

[C# Url Builder Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759881/c-sharp-url-builder-class)

*As far as I know, there isn't anything "out-of-the-box" in .NET that allows one a fluent interface to construct the `Url` and `QueryString`.*

Answer (score 0):

```
// In webform code behind: 
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace testURL
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NameValueCollection queryString = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

            queryString["firstKey"] = "a";
            queryString["SecondKey"] = "b";

            string url=GenerateURL(queryString); // call function to get the url
        }

        private string GenerateURL(NameValueCollection nvc)
        {
            return "index.aspx?" + string.Join("&", Array.ConvertAll(nvc.AllKeys, key => string.Format("{0}={1}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(nvc[key]))));
        }

    }
}


    // To get information to generate URL in MVC please check the following tutorial:
    http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/generating-traditional-urls-with-asp-net-mvc3/
```