# Path.Combine for URLs (part 2)

Tags: c#, path, uri

For awhile now, I've been searching for a Path.Combine method that works on URLs. This is similiar to [Path.Combine for URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372865/path-combine-for-urls) with one big difference.

I'll illustrate with an example. Say we have a base url: `http://example.com/somefolder` and a file: `foo.txt`. Thus, the full path would be: `http://example.com/somefolder/foo.txt`. Sounds simple, right? Ha.

I tried the Uri class: `Uri.TryCreate(new Uri("http://example.com/somefolder"), "foo.txt", out x);` which resulted in `"http://example.com/foo.txt"`.

Then I tried Path: `System.IO.Path.Combine("http://example.com/somefolder", "foo.txt");` which resulted in `"http://example.com/somefolder\foo.txt"`... Closer, but still no.

For kicks, I then tried: `System.IO.Path.Combine("http://example.com/somefolder/", "foo.txt")` which resulted in `"http://example.com/somefolder/foo.txt"`.

The last one worked, but it's basically doing string concatenation at that point.

So I think I have two options:

- Use Path.Combine and replace all \ with /
- Use basic string concatenation

Am I missing a built in framework method for this?

**UPDATE:** The usage case I have is for downloading a bunch of files. My code looks like this:

```
    public void Download()
    {
        var folder = "http://example.com/somefolder";
        var filenames = getFileNames(folder);

        foreach (var name in filenames)
        {
            downloadFile(new Uri(folder + "/" + name));
        }
    }
```

I'm miffed at having to use string concat in the Uri constructor, as well having to check if the slash is needed (which I omitted in the code).

It seems to me that what I'm trying to do would come up a lot, since the Uri class handles a lot of other protocols besides http.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Flurl](https://flurl.io) [disclosure: I'm the author] is a tiny URL builder library that can fill the gap with its `Url.Combine` method:

```
string url = Url.Combine("http://www.foo.com/", "/too/", "/many/", "/slashes/", "too", "few");
// result: "http://www.foo.com/too/many/slashes/too/few"
```

You can get it via NuGet: `Install-Package Flurl`.

I also wanted to point out that you can dramatically improve the efficiency of your code by downloading the files in parallel. There's a couple ways to do that. If you're on .NET 4.5 or above and can rewrite `downloadFile` as an async method, then your best option would be to replace your `for` loop with something like this:

```
var tasks = filenames.Select(f => downloadFileAsync(Url.Combine(folder, f)));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Otherwise, if you're stuck on .NET 4, you can still achieve parallelism easily by using [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx):

```
Parallel.ForEach(filenames, f => downloadFile(Url.Combine(folder, f)));
```

Comment: Indeed, I did parallelize the downloads with ForEach. I just cut it because it wasn't relevant for the question. Interesting link, though. I'll check it out and possibly change the accepted answer.

Comment: What's the licence the code under on? can I use it on my proprietary code?

Comment: Absolutely. [MIT license](http://choosealicense.com/licenses/mit/), so it's about as permissive as it gets. You just can't sue me. :)

Comment: Really useful Lib! Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @ToddMenier: I forget to say thank you! Really useful :)

Answer (score 10):

This is how the Uri class works.

```
var otherUri = new Uri("http://example.com/somefolder"));
// somefolder is just a path
var somefolder = otherUri.GetComponents(UriComponents.PathAndQuery, UriFormat.UriEscaped);

// example one
var baseUri = new Uri("http://example.com/");   
var relativeUri = new Uri("somefolder/file.txt",UriKind.Relative);
var fullUri = new Uri(baseUri, relativeUri);

// example two
var baseUri = new Uri("http://example.com/somefolder"); 
var relativeUri = new Uri("somefolder/file.txt",UriKind.Relative);
var fullUri = new Uri(baseUri, relativeUri);

// example three
var baseUri = new Uri("http://example.com/");   
var fullUri = new Uri(baseUri, "somefolder/file.txt");
```

Basically do it via string manipulation simplest and do

```
var isValid = Uri.TryCreate(..., out myUri);
```

If you want to find out more.
Check out this post [C# Url Builder Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759881/c-sharp-url-builder-class)

**Updated answer**

When referring to base uri it will always be http://example.com/ anything to the right is just path.

```
void Main()
{
    var ub = new UriBuilder("http://example.com/somefolder");
    ub.AddPath("file.txt"); 
            var fullUri = ub.Uri;
}
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static UriBuilder AddPath(this UriBuilder builder, string pathValue)
    {
    var path = builder.Path;

    if (path.EndsWith("/") == false)
    {
        path = path + "/";
    }

    path += Uri.EscapeDataString(pathValue);

    builder.Path = path;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the link (and examples) you posted don't do what I want. I simply want to take a base URI path and append a filename to it. I'm using simple string concatenation, but I cannot believe that such a simple (common) usage isn't supported by the URI class. I'll update the post with an example usage and some mire details.

Comment: The uri class intent is just simply not what you are after. Updated the answers to help you achieve what you want.

Comment: Seems like a large hole missing in the framework... Maybe JonSkeet made something to plug it...

Answer (score 2):

I have a static method for this purpose:

```
// Combines urls like System.IO.Path.Combine
// Usage: this.Literal1.Text = CommonCode.UrlCombine("http://stackoverflow.com/", "/questions ", " 372865", "path-combine-for-urls");
public static string UrlCombine(params string[] urls) {
    string retVal = string.Empty;
    foreach (string url in urls)
    {
        var path = url.Trim().TrimEnd('/').TrimStart('/').Trim();
        retVal = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(retVal) ? path : new System.Uri(new System.Uri(retVal + "/"), path).ToString();
    }
    return retVal;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a LINQ version of something close to the above answer.

```
public static string UrlCombine( this string root, params string[] parts)
{
    return parts
        .Select(part => part.Trim().TrimEnd('/').TrimStart('/').Trim())
        .Aggregate(root, (current, path) => current + ("/" + path));
}

var x = "http://domain.com";

var p = "path";

var u = x.UrlCombine(p, "test.html"); // http://domain.com/path/test.html
```

Comment: You don't need all that trimming... `Trim(' ', '/')` will do it.

Comment: That would work for spaces and /  It is not identical to the previous code as Trim deals with all white-space not just spaces.  But I like it and for a URL should work well.

Answer (score -1):

Omg, why all of you write such complex code? It is very simple:

```
private string CombineUrl(params string[] urls)
{
    string result = "";

    foreach (var url in urls)
    {
        if (result.Length > 0 && url.Length > 0)
            result += '/';

        result += url.Trim('/');
    }

    return result;
}
```

Example of use:

```
var methodUrl = CombineUrl("http://something.com", "/task/status/", "dfgd/", "/111", "qqq");
```

Result url is "http://something.com/task/status/dfgd/111/qqq"

Comment: What about if the url ends with a slash? For example, `CombineUrl("http://example.com", "/task/status/");` returns `http://example.com/task/status` instead of `http://example.com/task/status/` as one would expect.